# Virtual Joystick in Android SDK

Tags: android, joystick

I want to make a virtual joystick in my Android application for controlling an RC car. How can I accomplish this? Is there an API that I can use to do this? The code samples that I have checked out online do not seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a look at this one, very simple (with documentation, etc.)
https://github.com/controlwear/virtual-joystick-android

Just add to your `build.gradle` file `compile 'io.github.controlwear:virtualjoystick:0.9.9'` and then:

```
JoystickView joystick = (JoystickView) findViewById(R.id.joystickView);
    joystick.setOnMoveListener(new JoystickView.OnMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMove(int angle, int strength) {
            // do whatever you want
        }
    });
```

#### EDIT:

As of new updates, `compile` is **obsolete**, instead you should use `implementation` or `api`, as follows:
`implementation 'io.github.controlwear:virtualjoystick:1.10.1'` (*1.10.1* updated version)

The `minSDK` as the author says is **16 (Android Jelly Bean)**.